# MySQL Quotation Mar

Tags: mysql, quotation-marks

I am super newbe in SQL-mySQL stuff and I want to query these entries that contain a column with a specific value but the value already has quotation marks in it, it literally looks like this, quotation marks are already there:
"Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland"
So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name LIKE "Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland";
```

returns
Empty set (0.00 sec)
which I know for a fact, is not true!
then I tried (I tried both with double quotes, with single quotes, nothing works)

```
select * from this_table where museum_name=" "Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland" ";
```

returns:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland" "' at line 1

Please let me know how I can query something specific if it already contains quotation marks.

Comment: you can use single quote while generating query

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name LIKE '"Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland"';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name LIKE "\"Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland\"";
```

To scape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just use the escape character `\` or use single quotes `'` or use `%` in `LIKE` clause.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name LIKE "%Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland%";
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name = "\"Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland\"";
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE museum_name = '"Museum Voor Land-en Volkenkunde, Rotterdam, Holland"';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the string by using backsalsh \

like

```
 SELECT * FROM <tbl> WHERE col1 = "gh\"gh"
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM <tbl> WHERE col1 = 'gh"gh'
```

both will work, but it is better to use first approach